# Unity iOS Build fails if Custom Editors are present

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

im trying to build an iOS Unity project on MacOS but the build process fails every time with the error "Script updater for Libary/Bee/artifacts/900b0aP.dag/Assembly-CSharp.dll faild to produce update.txt file" followed by some more errors stating there are some unknown namespaces all linking to standard Unity Editor Scripting Namespaces (like EditorWindow etc.). When i open the scripts in Visual Studio i dont get any errors of missing namespaces or references. When i remove all my custom Editor Windows the App builds no problem.
Maybe also important to mention: The project gets developed on 2 machines, 1 Window 1 MacOS. Both share/update their data trough GitHub Desktop. .gitignore files for Unity are active. The current project version is the first init from the windows machine then pulled trough GitHub by the MacOS machine. All iOS important build setting (like iOS Version, Architecture etc.) allready got configured on the Windows machine and are set on the Mac machine as well. In the past i never had any problem developing Apps this way but all my past projects never used custom editor tools with custom editor windows so i kinda suggest that could be the main reason of the error, especially bc the build goes trough fine if they are removed.

I allready tried a suggestion of deleting the Libary folder so it will be rebuilt by Unity but it didn't solve my problem. Does anyone may have a idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you put the editor scripts in an Editor folder? are any references to them marked in conditional compiles for editors?

Comment: First one fixed my problem, thanks!